# Open file in editor with a single click in Webstorm?

Tags: webstorm

How can I have files and folders open with a single click in Webstorm.

What I want is the default behaviour for Sublime and VS Code.

Ive found old articles on this subject but they don't deal with the latest version, currently 2018.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206735235-Open-file-in-editor-with-one-click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article is old, but still valid. You can enable '**Autoscroll to source**' Project tool window option to open file on single click.

[image]

Comment: I cant find that option in the 2018 version.

Comment: it's definitely there - screenshot is taken in 2018.1.2.

Comment: Confirmed it's still there in the options menu for the project view. Wow, would never in a million years think that would be related to single vs. double click to open a file.