# Can I make Webstorm open files and folders with a single click, but also close the file again when you click on a different file?

Tags: webstorm

Basically I want file and folder navigation in Webstorm to match the default behaviour of Sublime and VS Code.

If I turn on "Autoscroll to Source" then files are opened with a single click, but they arn't closed again when I click off of them. This means my workspace gets cluttered up very quickly. See this link:

[Open file in editor with a single click in Webstorm?](https://superuser.com/questions/1319523/open-file-in-editor-with-a-single-click-in-webstorm)

Answer (score 0):

there is no such feature in webStorm; please vote for  [IDEA-124569](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124569) and linked tickets.
You can use **View/Quick Definition** (`Ctrl+Shift+I` in default keymap) to preview the file without opening it in editor.